# Datalist Control not showing any Paragraphs

Tags: c#, sql

I have a datalist control that gets populated from a htmlTextEditor control. The Datalist is ignoring all my paragraphs.

In the htmlTextEditor I Enter:
Test - Please Ignore

Test

Test

Test

But the Datalist shows
Test - Please IgnoreTesttesttest

What is happening here??? Help!!

In the Database the text looks like below.

**Test - Please Ignore**

Test

test

test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. It turned out that it was just a css stylesheet setting that was setting the paragraph to display: inline-block.

I removed that setting and all good now